# Load C object files inside emacs toplevel

Tags: emacs, ocaml

I am trying to load .cmo file for ocaml code that calls external C functions
in my emacs ocaml toplevel using `#load "somefile.cmo"` When I do, I get this error:

`The external function 'some_function' is not available.`

Is there any way to get rid of this error inside emacs toplevel? How is it
possible to load C object files inside emacs toplevel?

Comment: I presume that module depends on another module which you did not load.  Where does the module come from?  Opam?  Did you try to load the whole package with topfind?  Please try to be more specific.  It's likely an issue with your specific setup, so we can't help you if you abstract file names and error messages.

Comment: Well the external functions are used in the .ml file who's object file .cmo I am trying to load in emacs ocamltoplevel. However, these functions are defined in a .C file and who's object files are .o or .so. It seems like I need to generate .cma/cmxa for the .C files and load them in my emacs toplevel? Could you please suggest how that can be achieved. 

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load the corresponding C functions automatically with `cmo` files.

If some library is *properly compiled, linked and installed*, you can automatically load its C library by loading its `cma` and `cmxa` files, *not* `cmo` nor `cmx`. `cma`/`cmxa` files can have information about which C dll should be loaded together. `cmo`/`cmx` cannot.

How to build `cma`/`cmxa` files which can automatically load their cooresponding C functions by yourself, is a different and higher level topic. I do not cover it since it does not seem to be your problem. You should read the reference maual, 19.1.4  Dynamically linking C code with OCaml code at http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.01/intfc.html

Comment: Well the external functions are used in the .ml file who's object file .cmo I am trying to load in emacs ocamltoplevel. However, these functions are defined in a .C file and who's object files are .o or .so. It seems like I need to generate .cma/cmxa for the .C files and load them in my emacs toplevel? Could you please suggest how that can be achieved. 

Many thanks.

Comment: Read the reference manual 19.1.4 first. 19.11 explains how to use ocamlmklib tool to facilitate the steps. If you try that, and if still troubled, please post a new question.